# Using the latest jQuery files in Visual Studio

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2012, nuget

When I use a web template in Visual Studio 2012 like MVC 4, the script folder is already filled with the jQuery files. All this is fine, except that each time a version that isn't the latest is used. I then have to either manually bring in the latest jQuery files or use NuGet.

Is there a way to automatically get the latest jQuery files when a project is created in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the template file directly to do this for all the new projects. more details follow [this link.](http://www.xavierdecoster.com/update-project-template-to-latest-nuget-packages)

*Note: I'd recommend you to create your own project template so you can always revert back to the default one in case you, or someone else, is going to mess things up*

**All Visual Studio (2012) project templates can be found here:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\
```

If you want to create some custom project templates, I'd recommend you to create them here:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Templates\ProjectTemplates
```

For the MVC4 CSHTML project template. You can find it here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033\MvcWebApplicationProjectTemplatev4.0.cshtml\
```

To modify the files, you'll have to edit them as Administrator.

Update the following section like mention here to update the dependency to version 1.8.2 by default.

```
<WizardData>
        <packages repository="registry" keyName="AspNetMvc4VS11" isPreunzipped="true">
            <package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" skipAssemblyReferences="true" />
            <package id="jQuery" version="1.8.2" />
...
```